# Traversing the filesystem in Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, filesystems

I have a very crude but effective file system browser in my application, and it worked just find until recently (I assume until I, and worse, my users, updated to Marshmallow).

The basic working of it is quite simple: I let the user start from the SD card (which I got from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`), and then I show the relevant file and all directories in the browser, adding artificially a `..` directory to navigate up the tree, unless the current directory isn't `/` already.

As I said, it worked just fine and it had a number of *very desirable* properties:

1. it allowed to navigate *very comprehensively* the filesystem: the user could visit pretty much everything with some rather minor exceptions (like some system directories and the `/data/data` directories)
2. it was easy to go from the SD card to the `/` file-system and then back to (possibly a different) SD card
3. it was very akin to the explorers the users where already used to (FileMangers, Finders, Midnight Commander, you name them...)

Now it doesn't work anymore, and **it's not a matter of runtime permissions** (I did check that part already).

What happens is as follows:

1. on my Nexus 5 the storage is located at `/storage/emulated/0`
2. I can navigate the storage sub-directories just fine (I do have the permissions), but *I can't go up to `/storage/emulated`* and, therefore, *I cannot reach the `/` filesystem*
3. it follows from '2' that I cannot go from one SD card to another (!!!)

Starting from `/` doesn't help either, as `/storage/emulated` is still not list-able from `/storage` (not that I would have expected differently), and I am therefore isolated in the root file-system.

**Question 1**: Is there a way to revert from this **windows-like `C:`/`D:`/`E:` bulls..t** the Os developers have *misguidedly* and *artificially* relegated us into, and get back the (beautiful) POSIX filesystem that is the true Android's birthright?

**Question 2**: If not, is there at least a way to get a list of all SD card locations, in a way that would allow to emulate the previous behavior?

Thanks!

Comment: Just found this and I have been having the same problem with Marshmallow with my own file explorer (File.listFiles returns null on "/storage/emulated").  In my case, when I get that null, I just treat it like an empty directory (I probably should make it clear that it is unreadable however).  This allows me to still go up (just treat each unreadable parent directory as empty), but not go back down.  This change is very unfortunate (and even looking at it using adb shell, it looks like it should be readable with permissions `rwx__x__x`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I let the user start from the SD card (which I got from Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())

[External storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) is not [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on most Android devices.

> then I show the relevant file and all directories in the browser, adding artificially a .. directory to navigate up the tree, unless the current directory isn't / already.

There is no requirement that directories above one of those returned by a method like `getExternalStorageDirectory()` be readable by your app. In general, as users of POSIX filesystems can attest to, just because you have access to a directory does not mean that you have access to parent or peer directories.

> I can navigate the storage sub-directories just fine (I do have the permissions), but I can't go up to /storage/emulated and, therefore, I cannot reach the / filesystem

This is not unique to your Nexus 5, nor to Android 6.0. You will run into problems like this all over the place, because you made an assumption that you have read access to parent directories, and that assumption is not universally valid. For example, on Android 4.2+ tablets, and Android 5.0+ phones, secondary user accounts will have different paths for things like `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` than what you are used to.

> it follows from '2' that I cannot go from one SD card to another (!!!)

You have no arbitrary access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4 and higher.

> Question 1: Is there a way to revert from this windows-like C:/D:/E: bulls..t the Os developers have misguidedly and artificially relegated us into, and get back the (beautiful) POSIX filesystem that is the true Android's birthright?

You can root your device, then arrange to fork processes with superuser privileges, that have read access to all facets of the filesystem.

Otherwise, as with other POSIX filesystems, you do not have access to everything.

> Question 2: If not, is there at least a way to get a list of all SD card locations, in a way that would allow to emulate the previous behavior?

No. First, as noted, your previous behavior was already unreliable, due to POSIX filesystem permissions. Second, you do not have access to removable storage in general, once again due to filesystem permissions.

You are certainly welcome to call methods like `getExternalFilesDirs()` (note the plural) on `Context`. If the device has removable storage, the second and subsequent `File` objects returned by these methods will point to locations on removable storage that you can read and write. However, you will not have access to parent directories or other random locations on the removable storage.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer (the link to your blog in particular is solid gold)!

I can only argue that while your remarks about POSIX permissions are 100% correct, *in practice* a setup with non-readable parents is hardly something that the casual-non-root POSIX user would stumble into, in a day-by-day usage.

This is why, at least before 4.4, my approach worked quite well in practice (and why I think the new design is a hateful departure from the original hackish spirit of the android platform).

*"O tempora, o mores!"* :(

Comment: @Rick77: "in practice a setup with non-readable parents is hardly something that the casual-non-root POSIX user would stumble into, in a day-by-day usage" -- a user might not, but a program very well can. Linux daemons routinely run under accounts that are restricted as to what they can access, particularly those daemons that function as servers. In fact, that's the very feature that Android is taking advantage of: each app runs as its own Linux user by default.

Comment: correct, but of little consequence: with the old ("wild" I might say) setup, the external storage was a "free for all" space, so the UID of the process was hardly relevant there (I might have got a random one at each execution, for what was worth...). Also the parallel with the deamon is again a proof that we are tackling the issue from different perspectives (theoretic vs practical?): users are not sys. daemons: they browse the "Download" dir, create some dirs of their own, save and read mp3... that kind of stuff. Until 4.4 no one prob. got stuck on a 700 (or cared, if he did... :) )

Comment: @Rick77: "the external storage was a "free for all" space" -- it still is. Your algorithm is going outside of external storage, by traversing above the external storage base directory. This is akin to complaining that on a locked-down Linux system that you do not have read access to `/home/` or `/` despite having read access to `/home/rick77/`, because you think that the entire hard drive is the home directory.

Comment: you are right, but isn't annoying then, that Android is moving from an open system (the *"hackish roots"* I was talking about in the first comment) to a *locked-down* system (And what for? Is the OS meant to be heavy multi-user, in a "user = person" sense)? Do you actually *like* to work or code a systems like that? Was preventing directory traversal and listing actually *necessary* to implement their vision of storage?! That's security-through-obscurity amateur hour stuff, and they could have done without it...

Comment: mind you: I'm not denying the merits of the new storage approach, it's just that it's a step from the "free and wild" Android approach I love, toward the artificial iOs way of life where everything is as sandboxed and tight leashed as it could be (there is a long way to go there, fortunately), and it makes me sad...

Comment: @Rick77: "Do you actually like to work or code a systems like that?" -- I haven't worked on an OS where I could assume read access to parent directories since Windows 95. I am fairly used to the concept. "it's just that it's a step from the "free and wild" Android approach I love" -- you haven't been able to assume read access to parent directories since Android was introduced.

Comment: keep assuming then, I'll keep a hold on reality, and the reality is that the approach *worked fine for a very wide range of uses* until 4.4 regardless of what the Android fs as a whole was (and your remarks for the contrary), and now it doesn't anymore and I'll have adjust (thank you for the info about that). Then we can go all day about `/home/cware/httpdocs`, `/Users/CommonsWare/DocumentsShared` or whatever, but I don't foresee you seeing behind "how a fs *can* be" (and I sure will not move from my own idea about "how a fs *should be*").